# Read and Write files to a server

Tags: java, file-io

I do not need help so much, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I'm building a project for one of my buddies and it is going to require me to read and write to a server. I want to know where to go to learn to study about reading and writing to a server Via Java. I've looked for about 30 minutes and everyone seems to have a different way to read and write to servers, I just want to learn the proper way to go about this.

Comment: It kinda depends on what you mean by read and write and what server type you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess when you say "server" you mean a remote computer that serves something. To be able to write into it, you need some kind of server software installed on that server. If you want some thing off-the-shell, install an FTP server as Stranger_in_the_night mentioned in his post. Or, write your own server that creates a ServerSocket and accept incoming requests.

Comment: My bad on not clarifying what I meant by server, I do not know the correct terminology, but my buddy has a Web server and my project is going to read and write files to his web server so he can approve and deny post that users put on his website.